# Move files matching a regex pattern

Tags: bash, regular-expression, wildcards, mv

I have a directory with several thousand files. Many of them are images where the filename begins with the image's resolution. The height and width of the images can be two, three, four or five digits long. For example:

```
 - 986x1088_lalbslj.jpg
 - 2043x924_fjnndkk.jpg
 - 9560x12643_fjknfd.jpg
 - 24x24_dnjkan.jpg
```

I'd like to collect all these images in a new directory (say `./images/`). Sounds simple enough.
The simple regex `[0-9]+x[0-9]+.*` matches these filenames, but as far as I've understood, you can't use regex with `mv`.
Ideally, I'd like something like this to work: `mv [0-9]+x[0-9]+.* images`, but of course, it doesn't.

It seems this questions has been asked a lot before, and I've already looked at several dozen (literally!) similar threads on this and other StackExchanges, but sadly I haven't yet seen an answer that helps me. Most of the time, the accepted answers are simply explaining that `mv` uses globs and not regex, or suggesting a corresponding glob that helps the author, but which doesn't work in my case. So I'm trying my luck by asking my own question – I hope that's OK.

I can't seem to condense my pattern into any reasonable glob, and regex doesn't work with `mv`, so what do I do?
Surely this must be possible somehow?!

Thank you very much for all your kind replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [extended globs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching):

> If the `extglob` shell option is enabled using the `shopt` builtin,
>   several extended pattern matching operators are recognized. In the
>   following description, a *pattern-list* is a list of one or more
>   patterns separated by a ‘`|`’. Composite patterns may be formed using
>   one or more of the following sub-patterns: 
>   [...]
>
> `+(pattern-list)`
>       Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns.

So:

```
shopt -s extglob
mv +([0-9])x+([0-9])* ./images
```

Comment: I like this answer but will prefer to replace `[0-9]` with `[[:digit:]]`.

Comment: @unxnut: any reason for your preference ?

Comment: It's simple.  However, the one I proposed is closer to what was asked (between two and five digits on each side of x).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following loop to achieve your objective:

```
for i in *
do
    echo "$i" | grep -qE "^[[:digit:]]+x[[:digit:]]+.*" && mv "$i" images
done
```

You can change the regular expression to specify between 2 and 5 digits as follows:

```
for i in *
do
    echo "$i" | grep -qE "^[[:digit:]]{2,5}x[[:digit:]]{2,5}.*" && mv "$i" images
done
```

Answer (score 0):

mv $(ls | grep YOUR_REGEX) destination_directory/

should do the trick

Cheers

Comment: Not if any of the files in the current directory contain whitespace characters in their name.

Comment: Names beginning with ```-```  could also be a problem.

Comment: I think your regex should handle that and you can verify if the ls | grep REGEX prints the contents you wish to perform the operation (in this case mv) on.